# Matlab 3D Sort by H then S then V

Tags: matlab, sorting, colors

In Matlab I would like to do a sort on color values in a particular order. 
Say for instance, Sort by Hue, then Sat, then Intensity (V). Or, by V, H then S.

Something like this:

```
% UNSORTED 
A(:,:,1) = [1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1]; 
A(:,:,2) = [1 1 1 1 1 3 2 2 3 2 2];
A(:,:,3) = [3 1 4 3 2 1 2 1 1 2 1];

% RESULT 
A(:,:,1) = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2]
A(:,:,2) = [1 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 2 2 3]
A(:,:,3) = [1 2 3 3 4 1 2 1 1 2 1]
```

I've struggled a day on this with no luck. Any help?

Comment: Do you really need `A` as a 1x11x3 array? Why not 11x3?

Comment: I oversimplified the problem, see below to see a more appropriate MxNx3 case, thanks.

Comment: So what's the desired result? Please give an example including desired output; and do so by editing your question, not as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method could be:

```
% UNSORTED 
A(:,:,1) = [1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1]; 
A(:,:,2) = [1 1 1 1 1 3 2 2 3 2 2];
A(:,:,3) = [3 1 4 3 2 1 2 1 1 2 1];

for ii = 1:size(A,1)
    A(ii,:,:) = reshape(sortrows(squeeze(A(ii,:,:)),[1:3]),[1,size(A,2),size(A,3)])
end
```

So we extract each 2D matrix, we use `squeeze` to delete the singleton dimension, then we use `sortrows` to sort each rows (with this priority 1->2->3). And finally we `reshape` this 2D matrix to restore the singleton dimension and obtain a 3D matrix.

Comment: This worked after reshaping the 3D image matrix to the way A looks here, then reshaping the sorted image back to the original! Thank you so much!